# Twisted suggestion for TCP client spawn processes

Tags: python, process, twisted, tcpclient, spawning

With a script that should start 3 different connection as client to 3 different servers, is it advisable to spawn the 3 clients? or it is unnecessary?

```
        p1 = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, test1
            ).connectTCP(Host, Port)
        p2 = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, test2
            ).connectTCP(Host2, Port)
        p3 = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, test3
            ).connectTCP(Host2, Port)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're asking here.  However, one thing I can confirm is that a TCP connection is between exactly two hosts: one client (responsible for "connecting") and one server (responsible for "accepting") (or sometimes simultaneous open where there are two clients and zero servers, but no one actually does that).

If you want to connect to three servers, you *must* create at least three connections.

Comment: I've confused a process with a connection. so 1 process will handle the 3 connection

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I still don't understand your question.